# python: create list of combinations from two other lists

Tags: python

I have the following two lists:

```
list_of_dicts = [
    {'book': 1, 'title': 'novice'},
    {'book': 2, 'title': 'novice'},
    {'book': 3, 'title': 'novice'},
]
names = ['Johnny', 'Mike']
```

I want to create a list of dictionaries representing the combinations of each of these two lists like so:

```
data = [
    {'book': 1, 'title': 'novice', name='Johnny'},
    {'book': 1, 'title': 'novice', name='Mike'},
    {'book': 2, 'title': 'novice', name='Johnny'},
    {'book': 2, 'title': 'novice', name='Mike'},
    {'book': 3, 'title': 'novice', name='Johnny'},
    {'book': 3, 'title': 'novice', name='Mike'},
]
```

This is what I have so far but there should be a better way:

```
data = []
for d in list_of_dicts:
    for name in names:
        new_d = d.copy()
        new_d['name'] = name
        data.append(new_d)
```

The reason I ask is for optimization reasons: the first two lists in my use case can be huge in certain situations.

Comment: Well you can not optimize it dramatically (different time complexity) since it runs in the amount of output dictionaries.

Comment: Do you actually need a list of dicts or would a generator of dicts suffice?

Comment: @Omni I'll be using the resulting list `data` quite a bit so pretty sure a generator wouldn't work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## A note on time complexity

We can not boost it dramatically (in the sense that we construct an algorithm with different time complexity), since the current algorithm already runs in the number of output dictionaries, and you can not construct a list of *k* elements in less than *O(k)*.

## Boost with *vanilla* Python

We can however use for instance list comprehension and more effective dictionary construction to boost performance a bit:

```
[{**d, 'name': name} for d in list_of_dicts for name in names]
```

If we compare this with the original implementation, we get for the following benchmarks:

```
old: 1.611422804009635
new: 1.3899883680278435 (-14%)
```

Benchmark program:

```
>>> def g():
...     data = []
...     for d in list_of_dicts:
...         for name in names:
...             new_d = d.copy()
...             new_d['name'] = name
...             data.append(new_d)
...     return data
... 
>>> def h():
...     return [{**d, 'name': name} for d in list_of_dicts for name in names]
... 
>>> timeit.timeit(g)
1.611422804009635
>>> timeit.timeit(h)
1.3899883680278435
```

## Using *generators* instead of lists

Frequently when dealing with large input, it is better to use a *generator*, since that means we never construct a full list of elements, but only calculate the next one when we need it. The advantage is twofold: in case we cut of iterating over a generator earlier, we do not waste cycles on calculating dictionaries that are never used, and furthermore we save on memory, since if the old dictionary is no longer used, the memory it occupied can be reused. The disadvantage is that if all elements are enumerated, there is some overhead that is wasted with the generator *protocol*. We can easily turn list comprehension into a generator, by using round brackets `()` instead of square brackets `[]`:

```
({**d, 'name': name} for d in list_of_dicts for name in names)
```

## Boost with pandas

We can also use pandas, if every dictionary contains the *same* keys. We can construct two dataframes and then join these, like:

```
from pandas import DataFrame, merge

da = DataFrame(list_of_dicts)
db = DataFrame(names)
da['_tmpkey'] = db['_tmpkey'] = 1

result = merge(da, db, on='_tmpkey').drop('_tmpkey', axis=1).T.to_dict().values()
```

Pandas will usually work slower for *small* datasets, but will usually lead to a significant speedup in case the sets are larger.

Comment: First option (boost with vanilla python) is perfect. Increases readability dramatically as well. Thanks!